# Javascript - Uncheck all elements not listed by an array

Tags: javascript, jquery, checkbox

Given an array of values, I want my code to disable all elements (checkboxes) related to that value and uncheck any of the ones it disabled which were previously checked. Originally my code just disabled them and did not uncheck them:

```
function allow(j, extended){
    $('[id^="'+j+'_extended_"]').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
    for (var k = 0; k < extended.length; k++) {
        $("#"+j+"_extended_"+extended[k]).attr("disabled", ""); //IE
        $("#"+j+"_extended_"+extended[k]).removeAttr('disabled'); //Other Browers
    }
}
```

However, this would first disable every element, then re-enable the ones which were allowed. This won't work for checking/unchecking as it should not check new ones, but only uncheck those which are no longer allowed. What would be the best way to go about unchecking the ones that are disabled at the end which leaving others checked/unchecked as they were?

Thank you for your time!

Comment: What are the arguments to this function?

Comment: @SamuelEdwinWard seems j is a id prefix and extended is the array. but what he wants?

Comment: i think he want to uncheck some check box that in array

Comment: The arguments are j which is just an index and extended which is an array of numbers which are to be allowed. So the check box elements will be of the form 7_extended_456 where 7 is just indicating the row in the table (you can ignore that part) and 456 is the specific "extended" that is to be allowed or disallowed. Don't worry about what extended means, it's simply a label. The array would them be something like [456,123,352]. If this is the case, the checkbox 7_extended_456 should be enabled and the check left if it's there. However, 7_extended_898 should be disabled and unchecked.

Comment: Sorry, my question wasn't completely clear.

Comment: However, I think I've solved my problem by passing in the array of the elements that are not to be allowed instead of those that are to be allowed.

Comment: I'm guessing you want to leave alone checkboxes for other rows, (in your example, would 8_extended_123 be unchecked?); this requirement would make the solution a lot more complicated.

Comment: Yes, this is correct. However, I believe the solution I found should work. I'll post it here after testing. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of passing in the array of the with the elements I was going to leave enabled, I passed in the array of the elements to be disabled. That way I could explicitly say to uncheck them as well. The resulting code looked as follows:

```
function disallow(j, extended){
    //First, allow all.
    $('[id^="'+j+'_extended_"]').attr("disabled", ""); //IE
    $('[id^="'+j+'_extended_"]').removeAttr('disabled'); //Other Browers
    //Then remove any that are not allowed.
    for (var k = 0; k < extended.length; k++) {
        $("#"+j+"_extended_"+extended[k]).attr('disabled', 'disabled');
        $("#"+j+"_extended_"+extended[k]).attr("checked", ""); //IE
        $("#"+j+"_extended_"+extended[k]).removeAttr('checked'); //Other Browers
    }
}
```

Thanks much for those that took time to respond.

Answer (score 1):

to change prop of object use this method in jquery

```
$("#checkboxname").prop("checked","")// to uncheck
$("#checkboxname").prop("checked","checked")// to check
```

and in your code

```
$("#"+j+"_extended_"+extended[k]).prop("checked", "");
```

i hope useful

Comment: Thanks for the response. I'm sorry, I should have been more clear. I'm looking for the way to disable and uncheck all the elements which are not specified in the array. I do know already the command to uncheck them. What I was unclear on what how to select all the elements which were not specified in the array. However, I have just chosen to pass in the elements that are to be unallowed instead of those that are to be allowed. Then with just a few changes to my code it should work. Thanks for your time though.

Comment: i think for the first you must uncheck and disable all check box with each() func and after that check the array and find which element must be check and enable, one question: you know the command to do check and uncheck and work with array and just want a algorithm to do job correctly?
sorry for bad english